# Volume decreases to zero and can't increase it

Tags: music, volume

Sometimes, my music volume decreases to zero and I can't increase it using volume keys. This problem is happening when I use headsets. Any solutions for this problem?

I am using Nokia Lumia 520.

I've already tried this:

1. Resting the phone
2. Removing headset (everything works fine as I remove headsets)

Comment: Which headset you're using?

Comment: Could the volume button be stuck?

Comment: What have you tried to solve the problem? Include steps like restarting the phone.

Comment: Volume button is not stuck.

Comment: In case anybody researches this further, this is a widely known and persistent issue on windows phone 8.* with the usage of the included Nokia headset. This is just one of few related bug with headset and apps audio management that I repeatedly observed over the last 5 years with different windows phones. And no, Microsoft doesn't care looking at the forums. They're too busy implementing streaming for the Xbox one which nobody needs...

Comment: I had this issue and my phone was pretty much bricked. I never found a way to get it working, even after taking the phone apart completely (you'll need a T5 torx bit to do this). Basically, the volume button is soldered to the mainboard, and there's no easy way to replace it, and if using canned air doesn't fix the issue, there's not really anything you can do to remove any larger particles easily. In my case, my phone started exhibiting this issue after water damage. I hope this info at least helps someone from wasting time trying to fix their phone.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned it works fine when you remove the headset, try replacing the headset with another. Your phone has support for headsets that have volume controls on them. If your headphones are not seated correctly, they could be triggering the signal for the volume.

If this still persists with another headset, take a flashlight and look down the headset hole. Look for some kind of debris that may be blocking it. You may have to remove it. I have used a paperclip before for this. But be careful!

Comment: I am using Nokia's headset that came with the device. I checked headset hole, it is okay. As I said problem is happening randomly so still checking with other headset.